# Auto scroll down with Scrolltop function not working in php/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So this piece of code is not working in my chat program. I've tried putting it in several places but I don't really have experience with javascript or php so I could use a little help here.

```
var elem = document.getElementById.innerHTML("chat-area");
elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
```

```
        // kick off chat
        var chat =  new Chat();
        $(function() {

             chat.getState(); 

             // watch textarea for key presses
             $("#sendie").keydown(function(event) {  

                 var key = event.which;  

                 //all keys including return.  
                 if (key >= 33) {

                     var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  
                     var length = this.value.length;  

                     // don't allow new content if length is maxed out
                     if (length >= maxLength) {  
                         event.preventDefault();  
                     }  
                  }  
                                                                                                                                                                                                            });
             // watch textarea for release of key press
             $('#sendie').keyup(function(e) {   

                  if (e.keyCode == 13) { 

                    var text = $(this).val();
                    var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  
                    var length = text.length; 

                    // send 
                    if (length <= maxLength + 1) { 

                        chat.send(text, name);  
                        $(this).val("");
                        var elem = document.getElementById.innerHTML("chat-area");
                        elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;

                    } else {

                        $(this).val(text.substring(0, maxLength));

                    }   


                  }
             });
        });
    </script>
```

So i expected it to automaticaly scroll down after every chat message. But it doesn't do anything with scrolling at all. The messages still enter the chat box, but you have to manually scroll down. I want it to jump directly to the bottom of the chatbox(where the new messages appear) when a new message is send.

Comment: The first problem I see is the way you select your chat area, try:
`var elem = document.getElementById("chat-area");`. You can have a look at the correct syntax here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Answer (score 0):

Since much of the code is in jquery try this:
$("#chat-area").scrollTop(124)
124- is your desired position